# Multiple user directories on EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, amazon-ec2

Im trying to set up multiple user directories on EC2 running Ubuntu, but im not sure how to set it up correctly so that i can serve files in the following format:

```
http://<ec2 ip address>/user_1/public_html/file1.html and
http://<ec2 ip address>/user_2/public_html/file3.html
```

and so on for every user that i add. I tried looking for the `httpd.conf` file but i coulndt find it i only found `apache2.conf`

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`mod_userdir` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_userdir.html)

The name of apache's configuration can vary, it can be `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`